# Error i n angular. Cannot GET /

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple application and I am getting this error. Cannot GET /. and in the console this.`Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at Object.SL_BBL_locer (chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/js/inject/translator.js:1174:41)
    at chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/js/inject/data.js:100:30`

I really dont know , what I am doing wrong. Here are my codes.

**app.module**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
      DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app';
    }
**app.component.html**

<div>
 <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
</div>
```

**dashboard.component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**dashoboard.component.html**

```
<div> Im here</div>
```

Comment: You error message is saying you are trying to read the property "checked" from a variable that is null and not an object. But the code you provided doesnt seem to be related to the error.

Comment: And what is this line doing: ` this.workSchedules = WorkSchedules;`? It appears to be assigning a type to an array?

Comment: @CodeSpirit thats the problem I cannot find anywhere in my code where I have a variable with checks

Comment: @DeborahK that line is assigning mock data to the array

Comment: @user3701188 You are not assigning mockdata with `this.workSchedules = WorkSchedules`, you are assigning a type just like DeborahK suggested. Or at least that we can gather from the code you are showing us.

Comment: I have taken all the codes out to the very basic but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your workschedule.module is a feature module. In this case you need to add the CommonModule to the imports property of @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [
       CommonModule,
       WorkScheduleRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        WorkscheduleComponent
      ],
      providers: []
    })
```

Comment: yes I have the WorkScheduleRoutingModule imported in the workschedule.module so the I imported that module in the app.module i guess thats all I have to do